# nginx match a folder in path and with no .html which needs to rewrite with .html appended

Tags: regex, if-statement, nginx, url-rewriting, location

I have a URL which contains subfolders in the path and may or may not contain .html.

e.g. 
https://www.example.com/store/test/en/test/ANYCATEGORY/ANDCATEGORY/OPTIONALCATEGORY/PROGRAMNAME/p/100002020

I want to match if the url contains "/p/" in the path AND there is no .html at the end.
If these conditions are met, I want to append with .html

e.g.
https://www.example.com/store/test/en/test/ANYCATEGORY/ANDCATEGORY/OPTIONALCATEGORY/PROGRAMNAME/p/100002020

I have tried with if statements and location but no luck with any of those.

This is what I have tried with no luck:

```
    if ($uri ~ ^(.*)/p/(.*)$){
      rewrite ^(.+)/$ $1.html permanent;
    }
```

```
    if ($uri ~ ^(.*)/p/(.*[^.html])$){
      rewrite ^(.+)/$ $1.html permanent;
    }
```

```
  location ~ ^(.*)/p/(.*[^.html])$ {
      rewrite ^(.+)/$ $1.html permanent;
  }
```

Comment: This result should be: https://www.example.com/store/test/en/test/ANYCATEGORY/ANDCATEGORY/OPTIONALCATEGORY/PROGRAMNAME/p/100002020.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a positive look ahead `(?=.*\/p\/)` for ensuring the presence of `/p/` and a negative look ahead `(?!.*\.html$)` to ensure the string doesn't end with `.html`. The correct regex to use is this,

```
^(?=.*\/p\/)(?!.*\.html$).+$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/E5Ilit/1)**

Then try rewriting your if condition the way you were doing, which should be this,

```
location ~ ^(?=.*\/p\/)(?!.*\.html$).+$ {
    rewrite ^(.+)/$ $1.html permanent;
}
```

Also, in your regex `[^.html]` this is a character negation and will only negate certain characters present in character set after `^` and for negating a sequence of characters, you need to use a negative look ahead pattern like I did in my regex.

Comment: Thanks you.. that works for https://www.example.com/store/test/en/test/ANYCATEGORY/ANDCATEGORY/OPTIONALCATEGORY/PROGRAMNAME/p/100002020/ but not with https://www.example.com/store/test/en/test/ANYCATEGORY/ANDCATEGORY/OPTIONALCATEGORY/PROGRAMNAME/p/100002020. It only works with a / at the end

Comment: ```
  location ~ ^(?=.*\/p\/)(?!.*\.html$).+$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
  }
  location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ $1.html permanent;
  }
```

Comment: @hem1234: In my sample demo url, you can see it works for both the URLs you mentioned, ending with / and not ending with slash. [Check here again](https://regex101.com/r/E5Ilit/2)

Comment: correct it works for both, it was only the rewrite ^(.+)/$ $1.html permanent; which changed to rewrite ^(.+)$ $1.html permanent;

Answer (score 0):

```
  location ~ ^(?=.*\/p\/)(?!.*\.html$).+$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
  }
  location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ $1.html permanent;
  }
```

Comment: Please describe what did you change and why, to help others identify the problem and understand this answer